# Cannot pinpoint error in creating a packer Ubuntu Image

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, consul

I am trying to build consul into an ubuntu packer image. Packer builds the image but there are some problems with it.

Specifically this problem:

```
==> amazon-ebs: debconf: (Dialog frontend will not work on a dumb terminal, an emacs shell buffer, or without a controlling terminal.)
==> amazon-ebs: debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
==> amazon-ebs: debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
==> amazon-ebs: debconf: (This frontend requires a controlling tty.)
==> amazon-ebs: debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
==> amazon-ebs: dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin:
```

This is my Json Code:

```
{
    "variables": {
        "aws_access_key": "{{ env `ACCESS_KEY` }}",
        "aws_secret_key": "{{ env `SECRET_KEY` }}"
    },

    "builders": [{
        "type": "amazon-ebs",
        "ami_name": "consul-client",
        "access_key": "{{ user `aws_access_key` }}",
        "secret_key": "{{ user `aws_secret_key` }}",
        "region": "eu-west-2", 
        "source_ami_filter": {

            "filters": {
            
            "name": "ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-focal-20.04-amd64-server-*",
            
            "root-device-type": "ebs",
            
            "virtualization-type": "hvm"
            
            },
            
            "owners": ["099720109477"],
            
            "most_recent": true
            
            },
        "instance_type": "t2.micro",
        "ssh_username": "ubuntu"


    }],

    "provisioners": [{
        "type": "shell", 
        "script": "./scripts/consul_client.sh"
    }]
}
```

And this is my script that I am running:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hello Consul Client!"

# Install Consul.  This creates...
# 1 - a default /etc/consul.d/consul.hcl
# 2 - a default systemd consul.service file

curl -fsSL https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-add-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com $(lsb_release -cs) main"
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y consul

# Modify the default consul.hcl file
cat > /tmp/consul.hcl.tmp <<- EOF
data_dir = "/opt/consul"
client_addr = "0.0.0.0"
ui_config{
  enabled = true
}
server = true
bind_addr = "0.0.0.0"
advertise_addr = "$local_ip"
bootstrap_expect=1
retry_join = ["provider=aws tag_key=Name tag_value=ConsulClient"]
EOF

sudo cp /tmp/consul.hcl.tmp /etc/consul.d/consul.hcl
rm -f /tmp/consul.hcl.tmp

# Start Consul
sudo systemctl start consul
```

On the AWS Console on the AMI section, the platform is showing as other Linux when the source ami is a ubuntu image. For some reason I feel like it's not being made properly and also I am not able to SSH into the Instance as well, I think this could be the probelm.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to resolve this error by setting the `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` environment variable to `noninteractive` when invoking the shell provisioner.

```json
{
  "provisioners": [
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "script": "./scripts/consul_client.sh",
      "environment_vars": [
        "DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

See https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/amd64/ch05s03.html and https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/explain-debian_frontend-apt-get-variable-for-ubuntu-debian/ for more information on this parameter.